# Реализация предпросмотра pdf файла

Tags: php, javascript, html, pdf

Нужно реализовать страницу предпросмотра многостраничного pdf файла, так чтобы оригинал невозможно было скачать. А тот контент который будет на странице вывести с водяным знаком и не приемлимым для печати и сканирования качестве.

Т.е. в моем понимании нужно все рендерить в какой-нибудь jpeg, накладывать поверх png и формировать галерею.

Есть ли более простое решение, без загрузки самих доков на сторонние сервера?

Comment: мои глаза >Т.е. в моем понимании нужно все рендерить в какой-нибудь jpeg, накладывать поверх png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возьмите какой-нибудь [Zend_Pdf](http://devzone.zend.com/1064/zend_pdf-tutorial/), измените качество, наложите ватермарки на страницы документа, возможно, имеет смысл удалить некоторые страницы документа. 
На стороне браузера любая защита может быть проигнорирована, потому что оригинал браузеру отдается, а значит, может быть скачан.

Answer (score 1):

Скачать можно все что видит браузер и даже все что не видит особенно пдф. так как сейчас куча downloaders которые подключаться к ресурсам напрямую(которые грузяться на вебстранице), и что ты там не накладывай поверх все равно можно выгрузить все.

Comment: Вы умеете скачивать книги из Google Books?

Comment: А че там скачивать ?
https://googlebookdownloader.codeplex.com

Comment: есть еще универсальный под маки загрузчик
http://tulza.net Tulza Downloader бесплатный в нем google books в картинках можно взять и выкачать

Comment: Все эти программы дают только то, что система и так позволяет увидеть. ТС спрашивает о таком методе защиты, а вы говорите, что защита не возможна. Вот я и привёл пример.

Comment: Ну да) как же без 5 вставленных копеек)))

Comment: Вы написали опровержение мыслей автора вопроса, но не ответ.